# Java JPA ORM OneToMany ManyToOne

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, orm

I am trying to define a bidirectional relation between two classes. The owning side being class Quiz, and the inverse being User. A user can create many quizzes, while a quiz can only have one user that created it. Every tutorial I find online states that on the owning side you specify ManyToOne annotation along with JoinColumn, and on the inverse side you specify OneToMany and mappedBy with the name of the owners field. However when I do this, the IDE gives me an error "Can't find inverse relation". Where am I going wrong with this concept? Any help or direction would be appreciated.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.2.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.1.0-m3"
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["src/resources"]

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:2.5.3'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:2.5.3'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2:1.4.200'
}
```

Quiz.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "quizzes")
public class Quiz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UserID")
    private User createdBy;

}
```

User.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    ...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy")
    @MapKey(name = "id")
    private HashMap<Integer, Quiz> quizzes;

}
```

I've tried changing to Map reference instead of HashMap, adding targetEntity option to OneToMany annotation and pointing to Quiz.class, adding explicit @Column(name = "[columnName]") to each class field, etc. Still IDE gives me error that "Can't find inverse relation". I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

This is an example I found online: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/jpa/map-with-entity-values.html

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the approach you are trying to follow is incorrect. You do not need to have a `map` object storing the keys and related entities between the association.

A simple `OneToMany` mapping can be achieved by something as minimal as the following example:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user")
    private List<Quiz> quizzes = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

And

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "quizzes")
public class Quiz {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @ToString.Exclude
    private User user;

}
```

I also think that the tutorial you are looking at, might be steering you towards a wrong direction. Check the following links for more concrete information:

https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/

Comment: Hey I appreciate the explanation and the links you shared. I see your point. I'll try it out. Thank you for the response.

Comment: I am more than happy to have helped you